# libx264 compiled with MinGW - missing __umoddi3, __udivdi3, _fseeko64 and __chkstk_ms

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker, x264

I'm willing to use x264 in my Windows project, so I've build the library from source using MinGW and gcc into a static library.

The library and the header are included correctly, the only problem is that linker now complains, because __umoddi3, __udivdi3, _fseeko64 and __chkstk_ms. Looks like this functions are a part of some standard library, but where can I find it in Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: can you try -lgcc during compiling/linking?

Comment: Yep, made no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry, how about -lmsvcrt -lgcc ?

Comment: Try to have these in your make file: "LDFLAGS: -lmingwex -lmingw32"
"CFLAGS: -fno-stack-check -fno-stack-protector -mno-stack-arg-probe"

Comment: gcc can't recognize "-mno-stack-arg-prob" flag. Without it, anyway I'm getting the same linker error from Visual Studio. Is it possible to use x264 as static library inside a Windows project at all?

Comment: You get those errors when you compile the static library with one compiler/runtime, and try to use in a different compiler/runtime. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Exactly, I need x264 static libraries in my Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't copy/past full answer here but you should read this [topic at doom10.org](http://doom10.org/index.php?topic=2079.0)
In short, you can't directly use MinGW compiled .a libraries (static or shared) in MSVS. You need to compile libx264.dll and make MSVS specific .lib library from .def file and than use this library for linking.

Comment: @David x264 can't be compiled in MSVS because its C compiler doesn't fully support C99. So this is not the option. You will need to have Intel C Compiler (ICL) to compile in MSVS or rewrite parts of x264 that use C99 features.

Answer (score 1):

You have compiled a static library in MinGW and are trying to use it in Visual Studio. That does not work. In order to use a static library, it must be compiled with the same compiler, and against the same runtime, as the program that uses it.

If you are set on using this as a static library then you must compile the x264 source in Visual Studio.